# Why does cooling down result in a decrease in density?

Tags: neutrinos, density, weather

In chapter one of the textbook by AC Phillips, we find "... as the temperature fell, the density of the universe became too low for the neutrinos to interact effectively with matter..."

This doesn't make sense because I thought hot air/gas was less dense.  For example, in weather, hot air is less dense and rises while cold air sinks.  If temperature falls, shouldn't the density increase?

Thanks, Ned

Comment: What is the context? It seems to be describing the evolution of the universe, which has nothing to do with the weather. I think the context will tell you that both density and temperature fell because of the expansion of the universe.

Comment: I'm not an astrophysics expert by any means, but I consider the author's wording to be ambiguous.  I understand the wording to mean that as the universe expanded, it cooled, and the density of the universe fell due to the expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ned, the story works like this (as pointed out above by sammy and david):

The thing that drove the cooling of the very hot early universe was, in fact, its expansion- a process well-accounted for by the laws of thermodynamics. A thorough and eminently-readable exposition of this whole process is furnished by Weinberg in his book, The First Three Minutes, which I highly recommend. It contains a straightforward accounting of all the details of how the composition of the early universe changed as its temperature dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that space itself expanded at the big bang.  I don't know if it's exactly the same thing, but read up on our sun - only at the core with huge temperatures and gravitational pressures is energy produced.